# Best WordPress plugin for on-page editing?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wysiwyg, editing

I am looking for a WordPress plugin to edit a page while looking at the final version of it. I need the ability to click and edit any element on a page. It should also be able to duplicate/delete/move elements.

For instance, clicking an image would bring up a menu allowing me to change the image, delete it, move it, duplicate it, etc. Does a solution like this, or something similar, exist?

Answer (score 3):

There is a plugin will allow you to edit the text: it's a limited-capability content area editor for on-page editing. I don't know of one that gives you the functionality you are looking for in working with images.

The plugin is called Front-end Editor. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/

It's based on Aloha Editor. http://aloha-editor.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use TinyMCE. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the [Raptor Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-raptor/) WordPress plugin for on-page editing. The front-end editor is also very impressive and works well for doing the job.

If want to read more about on-page editing WordPress plugins check out http://webdesignerhu.com/wordpress-plugins-for-on-page-editing/

Comment: The second link is (effectively) broken (the domain name expired).

Answer (score 0):

We recently released a page builder tool that does exactly what you're looking for. It's efficient and simple to use. Plus, there is a free version!

[FastLine Page Builder Plugin](http://themes.fastlinemedia.com/)